# When i am clicking cancel button my app is getting closed??help me out

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

//When i am clicking cancel button my application is geting closed ??

void abcdialog::oncde()
{

```
AfxMessagebox("Quit",MB_OKCANCEL);

CDialog::OnOK();
```

abcdialog::oncancel(); ->giving the same result

}

Comment: Show some more code. Put a breakpoint on "CDialog::OnOK();" and check if it gets hit both when you click on Cancel and whtn you click on OK.

Answer (score 2):

You did not test the return value from AfxMessagebox, so OnOK() is called whether you click OK or Cancel.

Comment: If AfxMessagebox returns IDCANCEL do not call CDialog::OnOK()